# Problem about recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Please suggest me the solution to the following problem

consider a function

```
function recurse(a):

  for child in a.childs:

      recurse(child)
```

Now I want to execute some code lets say

```
print "Program ends here"
```

when the program is done with recursion,so how can I know when the recursion will end?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various answers proposed so far, which sum up to "do it outside of `recurse`", are fine.  But if you're keen to do it **inside** `recurse`, that's not hard either (just marginally less efficient):

```
function recurse(a, _toplevel=True):
  for child in a.childs:
      recurse(child, False)
  if _toplevel:
      print "Recursion done!"
```

The leading `_` in the name of the `_toplevel` argument indicates it's private, so callers know **not** to pass it.

Similar solutions involve keeping track of the *level* of recursion (not just whether it's top level or not, but "how deep you are" in general):

```
function recurse(a, _level=0):
  for child in a.childs:
      recurse(child, _level + 1)
  if _level == 0:
      print "Recursion done!"
```

While precious in other cases (e.g. printing out nested structures with indents) it's not needed here (and there's another marginal loss of efficiency compared with the first solution I gave, based on the `_toplevel` boolean).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

```
recurse(something)
print "Program ends here"
```

When the recursive function is done, the program will continue with the next statement, just like with any other function. That the function was recursive doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a default parameter:

```
function recurse(a, top=True):
    for child in a.childs:
        recurse(child, False)
    if top: print("Program ends here.")

recurse(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but the recursion will be done when the highest level completes.

A new function that wraps recurse() could do this:

```
function do_recursion(a):
    res = recurse(a)
    print "Program ends here"
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the print statement after the first call to recurse.

```
def main():
    a = NodeOfSomeSort()
    recurse(a)
    print "Recursion done!"
```